# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) |php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 

function debug_to_console($data) {
    $output = $data;
    if (is_array($output))
        $output = implode(',', $output);

    echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );</script>";
}


 ?>

<?php
    include("config.php");
    include("redirect.php");
    session_start();
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
      // username and password sent from form 
     $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['fname']);
     $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['lname']);
     $melli_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['melli_code']); 
     $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Email']); 
     $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['phone']); 
     $Pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Pass1']);
     $Pass2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Pass2']);
     $mycheckbox = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['checkbox']);
     $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['type']); 
     $Token=rand();
      debug_to_console($Token);
      if($Pass1 == $Pass2 && $mycheckbox==1)
         {
      $sql="INSERT INTO Users (Username, Pass) VALUES ('$Email', '$Pass1')";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      

      $sql = "INSERT INTO User_info (fname, lname,melli_code,Email,phone ,Token)
      VALUES ('$fname', '$lname','$melli_code','$Email','$phone','$Token')";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];
      debug_to_console($Email);
      $_SESSION['Token']=$Token;
      redirect("validation.php");         
     }
      if($Pass1 != $Pass2)
      {
           $error = "مقدار پسوردها با هم برابر نیستند.!";
          redirect("register.php?id=$error");
      }
      if( $mycheckbox!=1)
      {
     $error = "باید با قوانین را مطالعه کنید.!";
          redirect("register.php?id=$error");
      }

    }  

?>
```

I have problem when I enter my data, it doesn't go to Redirect path. and show this error in console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I check everything, like name and config code and everything could be related but it's still the same. I'm pretty sure that my config has right values.

Comment: which redirect fails? the one to validation.php? then you have to check the validation.php file. Normally the 500 comes if you have an syntax error in that file

Comment: I checked it and then changed it to redirect another file, but it didn't change.

Comment: When you have a 500 error, the first place to check is the web server error log.